# Where to find process table in linux files?

Tags: linux, process, kernel, init, pid

I am trying to edit my custom linux kernel to add some more features like saving a flag true/false for each process.

I know from my self-learning that each process has a table where it saves its pid and other stuff, my question is where that table in defined?

I searched a lot in linux file and couldn't find it.

---

Small Note: I want to set this flag to 0 when the init process starts, can someone guide me at which file pid of init process is initialised to 0 so I can add my own code?

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of [`struct task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.2/source/include/linux/sched.h#L649) in `include/linux/sched.h`.